# Javascript compare single int to int array

Tags: javascript, compare

I have two vars like so:

```
var numberArray = [0,10,20,30,40,50];
var chosenNumber = 20;
```

How do I compare `chosenNumber` to `numberArray` to access its key in the array (`[2]`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you might want to use indexOf:

```
var index = numberArray.indexOf(chosenNumber);
```

Comment: so simple. so clean +1. ( my mind went to very far directions - and not this simple one...)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you want to grab the index?

If so, use `.indexOf()` like

```
numberArray.indexOf( chosenNumber ); // 2
```

If you pass in a value to `.indexOf()` which can not get found in the array, it returns -1 instead. Since `Arrays` in ECMAscript are just "special" Objects, each *key* behind a value is just the numerical index.

```
numberArray = {
    0: 0,
    1: 10,
    2: 20,
    3: 30 // and so forth
};
```

If we would create a new Object that inherits from `Array.prototype` and also give it a `length` property, tada, we would have just created a Javascript Array.

Comment: For not found returns -1, not `undefined`.